# Exception Value: (2002, "Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (111)")

Tags: python, mysql, django, sockets, mysql-python

Hello guys I'm getting this error again and again on my deployment server. The site seems to work fine for some time but then again it crashes and shows this error

This is the trace back `

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://getfbstuff.com/

Django Version: 1.6.2
Python Version: 2.7.3
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'downloader',
 'ckeditor',
 'django.contrib.sitemaps')
Installed Middleware:
('django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  114.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/views/decorators/cache.py" in _cache_controlled
  38.             response = viewfunc(request, *args, **kw)
File "/home/getfbstuff/public_html/getfbstuff.com/fb/downloader/views.py" in index
  23.   if seo:
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in __nonzero__
  100.         self._fetch_all()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in _fetch_all
  854.             self._result_cache = list(self.iterator())
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in iterator
  220.         for row in compiler.results_iter():
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py" in results_iter
  709.         for rows in self.execute_sql(MULTI):
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py" in execute_sql
  781.         cursor = self.connection.cursor()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/__init__.py" in cursor
  157.             cursor = self.make_debug_cursor(self._cursor())
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/__init__.py" in _cursor
  129.         self.ensure_connection()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/__init__.py" in ensure_connection
  124.                 self.connect()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/utils.py" in __exit__
  99.                 six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/__init__.py" in ensure_connection
  124.                 self.connect()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/__init__.py" in connect
  112.         self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py" in get_new_connection
  435.         conn = Database.connect(**conn_params)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQLdb/__init__.py" in Connect
  81.     return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py" in __init__
  187.         super(Connection, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs2)

Exception Type: OperationalError at /
Exception Value: (2002, "Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (111)")`
```

Please help me I cant figure out what I had done wrong. I followed these steps to configure mysql and django [www.saltycrane.com/blog/2008/07/how-set-django-mysql-ubuntu-hardy/](http://www.saltycrane.com/blog/2008/07/how-set-django-mysql-ubuntu-hardy/)

I do not face such problem in my local machine.
Thanks in advance

Comment: What version of django do you use? After attempt to reload page it's work?

Comment: u did `sudo service mysql start` ?

Comment: Eugene No I have to restart the server

Comment: I did that too but again after 1 or 2 days i get the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The settings I choose was right, the problem was caused because I was running out of RAM as soon as the number of visitors increased and that's why whenever I restarted the server, the problem was gone.

So now I have increased my RAM from 512MB to 1GB, and never got any error since then.